# how should I user python decorator without changing the function name?

Tags: python, decorator

```
def decorate(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@decorate
def test(a=1,b=2):
    return a+b

print test.__name__
```

the result is wrapper. Is there any way make the result is "test"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `functools.wraps`:

```
from functools import wraps

def decorate(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@decorate
def test(a=1,b=2):
    return a+b

print test.__name__
```

Comment: @马新民 Awesome! If this was a good answer for you, feel free to accept it by clicking on the tick below the vote tally. Thanks!